OnClick button is not working with HandleEdit
I was trying to add the checkbox functionality to my todo list and the button is not working on click. See in the the handleEdit function I tried to add that functionality, but the button on clicking is not working, also I am going to add a linethrough feature to my completed tasks in the ToDoList. How can I add that without any problem and what edits to do in my server code? Please suggest.
const Home = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/get")
      .then((result) => setTodos(result.data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  const handleEdit = (id) => {
    axios.put("http://localhost:3001/update/${id}")
      .then((result) => {
       console.log(result)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
   }
   return (
    <div className="home">
      <h2>To Do List</h2>
      <Create />
      {todos.length === 0 ? (
        <div>
          <h3>No Record</h3>
        </div>
      ) : (
        todos.map((todo) => (
          <div className="display-task">
            <div className="checkbox" onClick={() => handleEdit(todo._id)}>
                {todo.done 
                  ? <BsFillCheckCircleFill className="icon"/>
                  : <BsCircleFill className="icon" />
                }
              <p className={todo.done ? "line_through" : ""}>{todo.task}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span><BsFillTrashFill className='icon'/></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

I am also sharing my server code:
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')

app.get('/get',(req,res)=> {
    ToDoModel.find()
    .then(result => res.json(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})

app.put('/update/:id', (req, res) => {
    const {id} = req.params;
    ToDoModel.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: id},{done: true}
    ).then(result => res.json(result))
    .catch(err => res.json(err))
})

app.post('/add', (req,res) => {
    const task = req.body.task;
    ToDoModel.create({
        task: task
    }).then(result => res.json(result))
    .catch(err => res.json(err))
})

app.listen(3001, ()=> {
    console.log("Server is running...")
})


